# How can i deploy Angular 14 web application on IIS server

Tags: devops, continuous-deployment

I had created Build pipeline for angular 14 on DevOps and it is working fine. i want to create release pipeline for same. but not able to find it for hosting server.

I am not able to find steps for deploy angular pipeline